# Psycopg2 shows different version number when inside dist-packages and outside it

Tags: python, django, pip, python-3.4, psycopg2

I have python3 and pip3 setup for running django. I installed psycopg2 version 2.6.1 using the command `pip3 install psycopg2`. But when I checked the installed version using the command `python3 -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"` it shows 2.4.5 (dt dec pq3 ext). But when I go inside /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages and check the version using the same command, it shows 2.6.1 (dt dec pq3 ext). I dont have site-packages directory inside /usr/local/lib/python3.4/

Please let me know possible solution to make the psycopg2 version 2.6.1 to be the default one even outside dist-packages directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I found the site-packages for my installation from python shell.

```
>>> import site;
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/dist-python']
```

Found that the folder /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages had psycopg2 folder. Removing that folder points to psycopg2 to 2.6.1 version.